# How to correctly download R script with Shiny Meta

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I am currently working with shiny meta. I have a simple app that allows me to download a .csv calculate the row means of columns 2:length(data). (its a specific .csv). What I want is to be able to download a an Rscript of my code using shiny meta. Currently when I press download it gives me a .htm

I have no idea what is wrong with this.

Any help if appreciated!

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(shinymeta)

# Define UI for the app
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title
  titlePanel("Calculate Grade"),
  
  # Sidebar with file input
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", "Upload CSV file"),
      downloadButton("download", "Download Results"),
      downloadButton("meta", "download R code")
    ),
    
    # Main panel with table output
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("code"),
      DT::dataTableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Read uploaded file
  data <- metaReactive({
    req(..(input$file))
    read.csv(..(input$file$datapath))
  })
  
  # Calculate means of each row
  means <- metaReactive({
    ..(data()) %>%
      rowwise() %>%
      mutate(mean = mean(c_across(2:length(..(data())))))
  })
  
  # Output data table with means
  output$table <- metaRender(renderDataTable, {
    ..(means())
  })
  
  # Download results as CSV
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("means_", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(means(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
output$code <- renderPrint({
  expandChain(quote(library(tidyverse)), output$table())
})

output$download <- downloadHandler(
  filename = "report.zip",
  content = function(file) {
    report <- expandChain(output$table()
    )
    buildScriptBundle(report, file)
  }
)

}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Currently when I press the Download button for `meta` it gives back an .htm which is useless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `shinymeta` package is a niche one but very important in my opinion. The code reproducibility in the shiny apps is a very valuable addition.

I see many problems with your app like the duplicated output id's and usage of `metaReactive` where you need the `metaReactive2` function.
With `metaReactive2`, you can use `metaExpr` to select specific parts of the code needed for reproducibility so e.g., req(input) can be skipped.

You did not provide the data so I use the `write.csv(airquality, "airquality.csv")` as an example dataset.

```r
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)
library(shinymeta)

# Define UI for the app
ui <- fluidPage(
  # App title
  titlePanel("Calculate Grade"),

  # Sidebar with file input
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file", "Upload CSV file"),
      downloadButton("download", "Download Results"),
      downloadButton("downloadr", "download R code")
    ),

    # Main panel with table output
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("code"),
      DT::dataTableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  # Read uploaded file
  data <- metaReactive2({
    shiny::req(input$file)
    metaExpr({
      read.csv(..(input$file$datapath))
    })
  })

  # Calculate means of each row
  means <- metaReactive({
    ..(data()) |>
      rowwise() |>
      mutate(mean = mean(c_across(2:ncol(..(data())))))
  })

  # Output data table with means
  output$table <- metaRender(renderDataTable, {
    ..(means())
  })

  # Download results as CSV
  output$download <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("means_", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(means(), file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )

  output$code <- renderPrint({
    expandChain(quote(library(tidyverse)), output$table())
  })

  output$downloadr <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "report.zip",
    content = function(file) {
      report <- output$code()
      buildScriptBundle(report, file)
    }
  )
}

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]